# Python Regex List into Another List

Tags: regex, list, python-2.7

I currently have a piece of code that runs mainly as I would expect only it prints out both the original list and the one that has been filtered. Essentially what I am trying to do is read URL's from a webpage and store them into a list ( called match, this part works fine) and then filter that list into a new list (called fltrmtch) because the original contains  all of the extra href tags ect.

For example at the moment it would print out A and B but Im only after B:

**A** [Core Development](http://docs.python.org/devguide/)',

**B**'http://docs.python.org/devguide/'),

Heres the code:

```
url = "URL WOULD BE IN HERE BUT NOT ALLOWED TO POST MULTIPLE LINKS" #Name of the url being searched   
webpage = urllib.urlopen(url) 

content = webpage.read() #places the read url contents into variable content


import re # Imports the re module which allows seaching for matches. 
import pprint # This import allows all listitems to be printed on seperate lines. 

match = re.findall(r'\<a.*href\=.*http\:.+', content)#matches any content that begins with a href and ands in >


def filterPick(list, filter):
    return [( l, m.group(1) ) for l in match for m in (filter(l),) if m]

regex=re.compile(r'\"(.+?)\"').search
fltrmtch = filterPick(match, regex)

try:

    if match: # defines that if there is a match the below is ran.
        print "The number of URL's found is:" , len(match) 
        match.sort()
        print "\nAnd here are the URL's found: "
        pprint.pprint(fltrmtch)


except:
        print "No URL matches have been found, please try again!"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:  Thank you for the answer issued however I managed to find the flaw

return [( l, m.group(1) ) for l in match for m in (filter(l),) if m]

I simply had to remove the 1, from [(1, m.group(1)) ). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the bottom portion of your code is mostly catching errors from the top portion, and that the regex you provided has no capturing groups. Here is a revised example:

```
import re
url = "www.site.com"  # place real web address here
# read web page into string
page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
# use regex to extract URLs from <a href=""> patterns
matches = re.findall(r'''\<a\s[^\>]*?\bhref\=(['"])(.+?)\1[^\>]*?\>''', page, re.IGNORECASE)
# keep only the second group of positive matches
matches = sorted([match.group(2) for match in matches if match])
# print matches if they exist
if matches:
    print("The number of URL's found is:" + str(len(matches)))
    print("\nAnd here are the URL's found:")
    # print each match
    print('\n'.join(matches))
else:
    print 'No URL matches have been found, please try again!'
```